# /dev/null: Permission denied - run script in background but do not ouput logs

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a script in background after being disconnected to SSH.

I am running this command

`nohup python batchscript.py ?& /dev/null &`

But it gives me `-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied` error.

I searched online and found these kind of solutions

`rm -f /dev/null; mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3`

I did that ... and ran my script again, I got same error

Also I am getting that `nohup.out` file being created, I dont want that.

**My ultimate goal:**
I want to run script even I am disconnected and most importantly I dont want it to output anything into any file, because log file will be huge.

Comment: That looks like it's trying to execute `/dev/null` as a program. `/dev/null` isn't executable, hence the permission error. Did you mean `>&` instead of `?&`?

Comment: Are you running this a `root`? If so - stop.

Comment: yeah I had typo ... i corrected it and now all ok ... I want to delete my question but I cant because there are answers ... please do not downvote me

Comment: ... really - if you are running stuff as root - stop

Comment: @EdHeal you mean running script with root? ... (sorry I am not linux expert)

Comment: Anything in unix as root is bad.

Comment: its the root of all problems? @EdHeal

Comment: You could say that. Do not run root unless you have to. And get into the habit of not running things being root.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pipe stdout to `/dev/null` along with stderr

Try

```
nohup python batchscript.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
nohup python batchscript.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That would redirect both stderr and stdout to null, thus there would be no nohup.out being created or no information appended anywhere.